# typeahead without bloodhound

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeahead

I'm under the impression that I don't need to use bloodhound when performing a remote call. I've tried running this code:

```
$("#iban2").typeahead({
    hint: false,
    minLength: 4,
    highlight: true
},
{
    source: function show(q, cb, cba) {
        console.log(q);
        var url = '@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new {controller = "Iban"})' + "/" + q;
        $.ajax({ url: url })
            .done(function(res) {
                cba(res);
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                alert(err);
            });
    },
    displayKey: 'iban'
});
```

Even though I get the results, calling the async cb from within the source function still does not work. Any tips on what's going on?

Thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why, but adding the limit option seems to solve the problem:

```
$("#iban2").typeahead({
    hint: false,
    minLength: 4,
    highlight: true
},
{
    source: function show(q, cb, cba) {
        console.log(q);
        var url = '@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new {controller = "Iban"})' + "/" + q;
        $.ajax({ url: url })
            .done(function(res) {
                cba(res);
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                alert(err);
            });
    },
    limit:10,
    displayKey: 'iban'
});
```